# ActionController::ParameterMissing (param is missing or the value is empty: film):

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

So, I'm getting the following error when trying to visit the films page on my app:

```
ActionController::ParameterMissing (param is missing or the value is empty: film):
2014-07-24T22:04:44.622356+00:00 app[web.1]: app/controllers/saas_admin/films_controller.rb:54:in `permitted_params'
```

See my films controller code below

**films_controller.rb**

```
class SaasAdmin::FilmsController < SaasAdminController
  inherit_resources
  belongs_to :studio, :finder => :find_by_id!, :param => :studio_id, :class_name => Studio

  before_filter :set_sort_fields, :only => :edit
  before_filter :build_collections, :only => [:new, :create, :edit, :update]

  def create
    create! { parent_path(parent.id) } # Redirect to studio in case studio_id is changed
  end

  def update
    @film = Film.find_by_permalink(params[:id])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @film.update(permitted_params)
        format.html { redirect_to saas_admin_studio_path(@film.studio), notice: 'Film was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { head :no_content }
      else
        format.html { render action: 'edit' }
        format.json { render json: @film.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  def index
    redirect_to parent_path(parent.id)
  end

  def show
    @clips = resource.clips.paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 30, :order => 'clips.position')
  end

  protected

  def resource
    # @film ||= end_of_association_chain.find_by_permalink!(params[:id])
    @film ||= end_of_association_chain.find_by_permalink!(params[:id])
  end

  def collection
    @films ||= end_of_association_chain.paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 30, :order => 'films.created_at')
  end

  def set_sort_fields
    resource.sort_name = '' if resource.name == resource.sort_name
  end

  def build_collections
    @studios ||= Studio.find(:all)
  end

  def permitted_params
    params.require(:film).permit(:name, :sort_name, :description, :short_description, :meta_data,
        :poster, :amazon_link, :active, :trackable, :country_ids => [])
  end
end
```

What might this be? I've been trying to figure it out for a bit but perhaps a fresh set of eyes will find it's something rather simple.

Cheers!

**Edit**

Here's the view code for films/new.html.erb

```
<h1><%= @page_title = "New #{resource_class}" %></h1>

<%= form_for resource, :url => collection_path, :html => { :multipart => true } do |f| -%>
  <%= render :partial => "form", :locals => { :f => f } %>
<% end -%>

<% content_for :sidebar do %>
  <%= render :partial => "saas_admin/shared/sidebar" %>
<% end %>
```

and films/edit.html.erb

```
<h1><%= @page_title = "Edit #{resource_class}" %></h1>

<%= form_for resource, :url => saas_admin_studio_film_path(parent, resource), :html => { :multipart => true } do |f| -%>
  <%= render :partial => "form", :locals => { :f => f } %>
<% end -%>

<% content_for :sidebar do %>
  <%= render :partial => "saas_admin/shared/sidebar" %>
<% end %>
```

**Edit 2**

For reference here is how the permitted params was defined when it was working:

```
 def permitted_params

{:film => params.fetch(:film, {}).permit(
:name, :sort_name, :description, :short_description, :meta_data,
:poster, :amazon_link, :active, :trackable)}

end
```

Comment: https://piechowski.io/post/action-controller-param-missing/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is happening because you have specified to require 'film' in your parameters through strong_params (specified above in your permitted_params code).

Whatever the view side is doing (whether its a link or a form/etc.), its not passing its parameters nested under 'film'

eg.) if you were to `raise params.inspect` in the controller action, you would see that there is no node for "film".

Most likely what is wrong is that the form code you have on the view side is not set to nest these parameters properly, are you using a `form_tag` for example?

Comment: Thanks @derekyau, I've updated the original post with the view code - hopefully it's helpful in debugging this.

Comment: Update, I've also added how the permitted_params was defined when it was working versus now.

Comment: which action are you trying to hit again sorry? update/create?

Comment: I'm trying to create a new film, so it's the new page that isn't loading. It would be the new action.

Comment: since the 'new' action doesn't actually use the strong_params to do anything, I don't see how it could be causing a problem... perhaps its more like the update/create action is failing and its trying to re-render new? As you said you are trying to 'create' a new film, so its likely the 'create' action that is actually being hit. Inside the create action, can you try to `raise params.inspect` and paste the output?

Comment: Cheers derekyao, I can edit/update a film just fine, however, the problem is that the new page is drawing a blank and throwing the following error in the heroku logs: ActionController::ParameterMissing (param is missing or the value is empty: film):
2014-07-24T23:21:29.662921+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/controllers/saas_admin/films_controller.rb:55:in `permitted_params' I've added raise params.insepct inside the create action and didn't notice anything different in the logs.

Comment: this happens only on heroku? can it be reproduced locally?

Comment: also you don't seem to have the code for `def new` in the controller, I guess its being defined by inherited_resources?

Comment: Good point! So, locally it throws this error when trying to even access the admin panel where the new action is: Couldn't find file 'chosen'
  (in /Users/me/Sites/multi/app/assets/stylesheets/saas_admin.css.scss:9)

Extracted source (around line #9):

6
7
8
9
10
11
12
          

 

<title><%= @page_title ? "#{@page_title} | #{ Saas::Config.app_name }" : Saas::Config.app_name %></title>
<meta name="description" content="<%= content_for?(:description) ? yield(:description) : "Illustrative streaming movie clips" %>">
<%= csrf_meta_tag %>
<%= stylesheet_link_tag :saas_admin %>

Comment: And correct, it's being defined by inherited_resources.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/57954/discussion-between-derekyau-and-user3399101).

Comment: It's referring to this:  *= require chosen

Answer (score 21):

I have got this problem too when I use Angular JS form to send data to backend Rails 4. When I did not fill anything in angular js form, the error will show `ActionController::ParameterMissing (param is missing or the value is empty:`.

I fix it by adding `params.fetch(:film, {})` the strong parameter into:

```
params.fetch(:film, {}).permit(:name, :sort_name, :description, :short_description, :meta_data,
    :poster, :amazon_link, :active, :trackable, :country_ids => [])
```

I refer to [code example to avoid ActionController::ParameterMissing (param is missing or the value is empty: film)](https://github.com/kirandc/rails4_crud_with_angularjs/blob/master/app/controllers/users_controller.rb)

I hope this will help you.

Answer (score 10):

Why not use so:

```
def creation_params
params.permit(:film)
end
```

It working for me! ;)