# ActionController::ParameterMissing (param is missing or the value is empty:

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, controller, parameters, actioncontroller

My controller seems to do what it is supposed to do, but I keep getting an error message that I could not figure out. I browsed SO for hours trying to find a similar issue, and I did find some, and did try what they suggest, but for some reason it is not working for me.

This is my environment

```
user@host:~/app$ rails -v
Rails 4.2.1
user@host:~/app$ ruby -v
ruby 2.2.0p0 (2014-12-25 revision 49005) [x86_64-linux]
user@host:~/app$
```

This is my controller

```
require 'net/http'
require 'net/https'
require 'json'
require 'uri'

class NrisController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_nri, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /nris
  # GET /nris.json
  def index
    @nris = Nri.all
  end

  # GET /nris/1
  # GET /nris/1.json
  def show
  end

  # GET /nris/new
  def new
    @nri = Nri.new
  end

  # GET /nris/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /nris
  # POST /nris.json
  def create
    @nri = Nri.new
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /nris/1
  # PATCH/PUT /nris/1.json
  def update
    <snip>
  end

  # DELETE /nris/1
  # DELETE /nris/1.json
  def destroy
    @nri.destroy
    <snip>
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /nris/1
  # PATCH/PUT /nris/1.json
  def apply_config
    @nri = Nri.find(params[:id])
    <snip>
  end

  private

    def set_nri
      @nri = Nri.find(params[:id])
    end

    def nri_params
      params.require(:nri).permit(:MyParam1, :MyParam2, :MyParam3, :id)
    end
end
```

I also tried

```
  def create
    @nri = Nri.new(nri_params)
    end
  end
```

and

```
  def create
    @nri = Nri.create(nri_params)
    end
  end
```

but I keep getting this error message

```
ActionController::ParameterMissing (param is missing or the value is empty: nri):
app/controllers/nris_controller.rb:176:in `nri_params'
app/controllers/nris_controller.rb:146:in `block in apply_config'
app/controllers/nris_controller.rb:145:in `apply_config'


Rendered /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_source.erb (2.5ms)
Rendered /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.text.erb (0.6ms)
Rendered /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.text.erb (0.8ms)
Rendered /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/diagnostics.text.erb (16.3ms)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: possible duplicate of [ActionController::ParameterMissing (param is missing or the value is empty: film):](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24944871/actioncontrollerparametermissing-param-is-missing-or-the-value-is-empty-film)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Postman or sending json for the Post request you need the set the header ContentType as application/json.