# Full Calendar: ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound (Couldn't find Event with 'id'=update)

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax, fullcalendar, dom-events

I am trying to include FullCalendar into my rails app. But I am having difficulty with saving after drag-and-drop.

I have 2 models - Event and Workout. Under event, there is workout.

I am able to get the full calendar up and running and save events, but when I drag and drop, then refresh, the events would revert to their original time.

In my console, it says:

> Couldn't find Event with 'id'=update.

When the events are created and saved through a form, they are properly displayed and saved on calendar. It's just when I try to drag-and-drop.

Here is my Event controller.

```
class EventsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_event, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  before_action :authenticate_user!

  def index
    @events = current_user.events
  end

  def show
    @event = Event.find(params[:id])
  end

  def new
    @event = current_user.events.new
  end

  def edit
    @event = current_user.events.find(params[:id])
  end

  def create
    @event = current_user.events.new(event_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @event.save
        format.html { redirect_to @event, notice: 'Event was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @event }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @event.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @event.update(event_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @event, notice: 'Event was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @event }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @event.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @event.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to events_url, notice: 'Event was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
  # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
  def set_event
    @event = Event.find(params[:id])
  end

  def event_params
    params.require(:event).permit(:title, :description, :start_time, :end_time, :workouts_attributes => [:id, :name, :category, :_destroy])
  end
end
```

Below is application.js file that controls the calendar.

```
$(document).on('turbolinks:load', function() {
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
      editable: true,
      events: '/events.json',
      eventDrop: function(event, delta) {
        $.ajax({
          type: "PUT",
          url: '/events/update',
          dataType: 'json',
          data: {id:event.id, start:event.start_time, end: event.end_time}
        });
      },
    });
});
```

When I try to drag and drop, I get a message below:

> ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound (Couldn't find Event with 'id'=update):
>         app/controllers/events_controller.rb:74:in `set_event'

When I check my console, all the events have IDs. But I'm guessing maybe when the event is being drag-and-dropped, the new event doesn't have an ID?

Answer (score 0):

Rails app is assuming `update` as `:id` when you are hitting this URL `/events/update`

```
$ rake routes

event  PUT  /events/:id(.:format)          events#update
```

change the url in ajax request to

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'PUT',
  url: '/events/' + event.id,
  dataType: 'json',
  data: { event: { start_time:event.start_time, end_time: event.end_time } }
});
```

Comment: ah thank you!!  Now my terminal says

ActionController::ParameterMissing (param is missing or the value is empty: event):
  app/controllers/events_controller.rb:79:in `event_params'
  app/controllers/events_controller.rb:49:in `block in update'
  app/controllers/events_controller.rb:48:in `update'

Does that mean I need to update my update method?

Comment: It's still saying the same emssage. Could it be because I on't have start_time and end_time and without date? Though i think start_time and end_time have date included..

Comment: you have to change the params to :start_time nad :end_time

Comment: Hmmm. I tried that, plus switching params from require to fetch like this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24944871/actioncontrollerparametermissing-param-is-missing-or-the-value-is-empty-film. With that, I no longer get any error, but the only problem is that calendar won't save when I refresh.