# Ruby on Rails: Can someone help me with this? Trying to create a record by passing json through an API and it's not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby

So I have a server model and I am trying to populate the table by passing json through a POST request in POSTMAN. But it inserts null value for all the attributes. Here's a the folder structure 
the folder structure

```
            railsApp
                app
                    controllers
                        api
                           v1
                              servers_controller.rb
```

This is the servers_controller.rb file

```
            class Api::V1::ServersController < ApplicationController

                 protect_from_forgery
                skip_before_action :verify_authenticity_token, if: :json_request?


                def json_request?
                  request.format.json?
                end

                def index 
                    puts params.inspect
                    @servers = Server.all
                    render :json => @servers
                end

                def show
                    @server = Server.find(params[:id])
                    render :json => @server
                end

                def create
                    puts params.inspect
                    @server = Server.new(server_params)
                    @server.save

                    respond_to do |format|
                        format.json {render :json => @server}
                    end
                end

                private

                def server_params
                    params.require(:server).permit(:url, :name) if params[:server]
                end
            end
```

Here's the json request:

```
            {
                "server": {
                    "url" : "www.google.com",
                    "name": "Google"
                }
            }
```

And this is the record that is being inserted

```
            {
              "id": 57,
              "url": null,
              "name": null,
              "created_at": "2016-08-16T14:45:23.207Z",
              "updated_at": "2016-08-16T14:45:23.207Z",
              "server_id": null,
              "cluster_id": null
            }
```

After researching stackoveflow, I found this: [ActionController::ParameterMissing (param is missing or the value is empty: film):](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24944871/actioncontrollerparametermissing-param-is-missing-or-the-value-is-empty-film)  But this is not working. Can anyone help with this? Thanks

edit: This is the output in the rails console.

```
                Started POST "/api/v1/servers" for ::1 at 2016-08-16 11:42:16 -0400
                Processing by Api::V1::ServersController#create as JSON
                   (0.2ms)  BEGIN
                  SQL (8.7ms)  INSERT INTO "servers" ("created_at", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2) RETURNING "id"  [["created_at", 2016-08-16 15:42:16 UTC], ["updated_at", 2016-08-16 15:42:16 UTC]]
                   (0.8ms)  COMMIT
                Completed 200 OK in 14ms (Views: 1.1ms | ActiveRecord: 9.6ms)
```

`</pre>`

Comment: How does the log file entry for that request look like?

Comment: @spickermann: Please have a alook at my updated content.

Comment: What is the purpose of `if params[:server]` in your `server_params` method? I've never seen/used that in my params methods. While it looks harmless, just curious b/c that the only unusual thing I'm noticing in your code.

Comment: Also, the log entry you included doesn't show the params that the server is receiving. You might want to include those too...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is in your request headers I think . You should send your request with headers indicating them as json . so you will need to send along this header as well  .
`Content-Type: application/json`

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Where do I add this line:     `Content-Type: application/json`   ?

Comment: From the log output that was added to the question, the server appears to already be processing the request as JSON: `Processing by Api::V1::ServersController#create as JSON`.  So I doubt this is the problem...