# params being passed from form_for but not inserted/commited to database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a form submitting a value to my create controller.  In the server log, I see the parameter (:style) being passed, but not inserted into database.  Does someone know how that could happen?

Server log

```
Started POST "/users/25/cupboards" for ::1 at 2016-08-19 19:11:39 -0400
Processing by CupboardsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"asWeoSFSisr62oMOPXZnb//KJ8LnAhT1h07NOm1Yn2O8t06N4yrDGugkd01AMQcujYzSahH+O7bEA/jpH+L9fQ==", "style"=>"WEEKEND", "commit"=>"Make a new closet", "user_id"=>"25"}
  User Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 25]]
  User Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 25]]
   (0.1ms)  begin transaction
  SQL (0.5ms)  INSERT INTO "cupboards" ("user_id", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?)  [["user_id", 25], ["created_at", "2016-08-19 23:11:39.219003"], ["updated_at", "2016-08-19 23:11:39.219003"]]
   (0.7ms)  commit transaction
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/users/25/cupboards/35/edit
Completed 302 Found in 46ms (ActiveRecord: 1.4ms)
```

Form

```
<%= form_for @cupboard, url: { action: "create" }, html: { class: "listform"} do |f| %>
  <%= f.label "ATHLEISURE", class: "welcomelistitem" %>
  <%= radio_button_tag(:style, "ATHLEISURE") %>

  <%= f.label "CASUAL", class: "welcomelistitem" %>
  <%= radio_button_tag(:style, "CASUAL") %>

  <%= f.label "PROFESISONAL", class: "welcomelistitem" %>
  <%= radio_button_tag(:style, "PROFESSIONAL") %>

  <%= f.label "WEEKEND", class: "welcomelistitem" %>
  <%= radio_button_tag(:style, "WEEKEND") %>

  <%= f.label "FESTIVAL", class: "welcomelistitem" %>
  <%= radio_button_tag(:style, "FESTIVAL") %>

  <%= f.label "DATENIGHT", class: "welcomelistitem" %>
  <%= radio_button_tag(:style, "DATENIGHT") %>

<%= f.submit 'Make a new closet' %>
<% end %>
```

Controller

```
def create
  @user = User.find(params[:user_id])
  @cupboard = @user.cupboards.new(cupboard_params)
 if @cupboard.save
   redirect_to edit_user_cupboard_path(@user, @cupboard)
 else
   render :new
 end
end
```

Params

```
private
  def cupboard_params
    # I used .fetch because .permit wasnt working. workaround found at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24944871/actioncontrollerparametermissing-param-is-missing-or-the-value-is-empty-film
    params.fetch(:cupboard, {}).permit(:style, :season, :neutral1, :neutral2, :accent1, :accent2)
  end
end
```

Thank you for the assistance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because your form submits the `style`attribute value like `style` instead of `cupboard[style]`. Looks like you're mixing `form_for` methods with `form_tag` ones and you need to replace `radio_button_tag` with `radio_button`. Also note that there are 2 forms of notations: either the function invocation `radio_button(:model_name, :col_name, 'value')` or the method invocation on the form object itself `f.radio_button(:col_name, 'value')`. Another issue with your form is that you're using label for each radio while it's designed to be used once for every group of radio buttons. Hence, the form should look like this:

```
<%= form_for @cupboard, html: { class: 'listform' } do |f| %>
  <%= f.label :style, class: 'welcomelistitem' %>
  <%= f.radio_button :style, 'ATHLEISURE' %>
  <%= f.radio_button :style, 'CASUAL' %>
  <%= f.radio_button :style, 'PROFESSIONAL' %>
  <%= f.radio_button :style, 'WEEKEND' %>
  <%= f.radio_button :style, 'FESTIVAL' %>
  <%= f.radio_button :style, 'DATENIGHT' %>

  <%= f.submit 'Make a new closet' %>
<% end %>
```

You'll then have to rewrite the `cupboard_params` method like this:

```
def cupboard_params
  params.require(:cupboard).permit(:style)
end
```

Didn't have time to check if this works, but seems like it should.

Comment: Thank you. That helped.  It was my radio_button_tag which I removed the tag.  And prepended the f.     I appreciate the help!

Comment: @Sammy Awesome! My pleasure.

Answer (score 1):

The parameter "style" is not being passed inside of `params[:cupboard]`. It is directly in `params`.

I don't see the other params (besides style) in your form so I'm not sure what is going on there but try this

```
def cupboard_params
  params.permit(:style)
end
```

Or change your radio buttons in the view to this

```
radio_button_tag('cupboard[style]', "ATHLEISURE")
```